# Unsupported operand types laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

```
insert.blade.php

       {!! Form::select('country', ['' => 'Select'] +$countries,'',array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'country','style'=>'width:350px;'));!!}      



  'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
         'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,


        When i m adding above     'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
         'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class, in app.php it give me the following error 
    Unsupported operand types laravel 5.2
        and 
    When i removed  'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
         'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    i m getting class 'Form' not found
```

what is the problem in the code ?
        where the edit the code?
what is the problem in the code ?
        where the edit the code?
what is the problem in the code ?
        where the edit the code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

`['' => 'Select'] +$countries` and your $countries is not in array form (Eloquent return object)

Try either adding toArray() in your Views or toArray() in your Controller

`['' => 'Select'] +$countries->toArray()`